# How to center an image shown by Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, center, nivo-slider

I would like to center an image shown by Nivo Slider. I have a very wide (1920px) image on a page that needs to be centered on smaller displays. In order to do that I need to change a background-attachment property to fixed and background-position to center.

How do I do that? I cannot set it in CSS because values gets rewritten by JavaScript. Probably the right place would be somewhere in `afterChange()` and `beforeChange()` functions but I really cannot figure out a right way how to do this.

Does anybody has any experience here? Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code, this is a vague shot; .nivoSlider wraps the images, so try this:

.nivoSlider{text-align:center} .nivoSlider img{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto}

Comment: haters gonna hate. that is the correct way to center something in css.